# Model that will predict how long it takes to compose a message (using Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, prediction

**Objective**

I have a dataset, df, that has millions of Duration values (in seconds) associated with unique userIDs. I wish to figure out a way to predict a static time that it takes to compose a message, given the data that I currently have. Is this even possible?

```
  UserID     Date                                     Duration (s)
  A          1/1/2020 1:10:00PM                       300
  B          1/1/2020 2:00:00PM                       800
  C          1/1/2020 3:00:00PM                       150
  D          1/1/2020 4:00:00PM                       100
```

**Desired Output:**

```
 static time that it takes to compose a given message:   300 seconds
 (hypothetically speaking once I find this appropriate model)
```

**dput:**

```
 structure(list(UserID = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
 "D"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(1:4, .Label = c("1/1/2020 1:20:00 PM", 
 "1/1/2020 2:00:00 PM", "1/1/2020 3:00:00 PM", "1/1/2020 4:00:00 PM"
 ), class = "factor"), Duration = c(300L, 800L, 150L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names =      c(NA, 
-4L))
```

**What am I thinking:**

I am thinking that I can use either Logistic Regression, nearest neighbors or a decision tree within Python (or some type supervised learning algorithm) but I am not 100% sure. Any ideas on how to approach this would be great!